# Is it possible to maintain meta keyword for each page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, global-configuration, metadata

I know that there is one place where we can actually maintain our keyword in Joomla Global Configuration-> Metadata Settings -> Site Meta Keywords, but is more like a place to dump all keyword of our website. Is it possible for us to maintain our keyword by each page? Will there be any effect on SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Joomla! provides a mechanism that starts from the general to the particular, the metadata management is a clear example, let me explain you how this works:

- The small modular part here is the article. If you go to each one, inside you have this option in the tab called **"Publishing"**, this replace the data in the menu item.
- If you go to your menu items, inside you can see a tab called **"Metadata"**, from here you can replace the data in the **Global Configuration**.
- If you don't add anything for articles or menu items, then the data in Global Configuration is the default data.

There is a limit for those, this depends on the search engine. Use as a starting point something like:

- Meta Description: **max 160 characters**.
- Meta Keywords: **around 10 terms**.

And related to whether it affects, I think yes, but for good, because you'll have a more diverse amount of data.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Effect would be normal SEO effect for metadata on a web page, nothing special above that.

Every menu item has a metadata tab, and every content item has a place for metadata on the Publishing tab. You can use those for page-specific keys. IIRC, the menu item one overrides the content item one, but I'll leave testing that to you.